# Sort list and force certain elements to be first

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of column names, `name_columns`. The list contains a subset of special column names, as well as non-special column names. The special column names are stored in the list `special_columns`. I want to sort `name_columns` so that the special column names appear first in the sorted list, in the order they are listed in `special_columns`.

The order of the  non-special column names is really not that important, as long as they appear after the special columns.

Example

```
special_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4']
name_columns = ['a', 'id_2', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'id_4', 'c']

#Do some smart sorting
#After sorting
name_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_2', 'id_4', 'a', 'c']
```

I have mulitple list's like `name_columns` and they all contain various subset (including none) of `special_columns`.
Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: What happened to `'id_1'`?

Comment: It's not present in the list to be sorted.

Comment: ah, I see. alright.

Comment: You can not sort list or you do not know how to set an item in list with indices?

Comment: I want to sort it according to the special rules outlined in the question.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to ask: "How to create an item in list?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about like this:

```
special_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4']
name_columns = ['a', 'id_2', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'id_4', 'c']

temp2 = set(name_columns).difference(special_columns)
sorted_cols = [a for a in special_columns if a in name_columns] + sorted(list(temp2))
#             \_____________________1________________________/    \_______2_________/
print(sorted_cols)  # ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_2', 'id_4', 'a', 'c']
```

Two parts to the answer:

1. `List-comprehension` that loops thought the `special` names and
   stores them in the result if they exist in the `name_column`.
2. Set operations to handle all elements of `name_column` that are not
   *special*

---

Few remarks:

1. if ordering of the *non-special* items is not important, you can remove the `sorted()` call on `list(temp2)` to speed up the code.
2. defining `temp2` is of course not required.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go for this one :)

Comment: @ElisByberi If you are going to be downvoting every answer to a question like this, you better write a script for it to get finished in this lifetime. I'll help you too.

Comment: I downvoted because we are not here to do homeworks.

Comment: @ElisByberi I don't see you encouraging OP to post code he might have written for the task or downvoting the question though..

Comment: I encouraged OP to simplify his question to: How to create an item in list? We are here to learn from each other and not to give free solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `key` function as an argument for `sorted`:

```
>>> special_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4']
>>> name_columns = ['a', 'id_2', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'id_4', 'c']
>>> print(sorted(name_columns,key=lambda x: special_columns.index(x) if x in special_columns else 10e99))

['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_2', 'id_4', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need really to sort the list? You could just create a new "sorted" one and use it. Something like:

```
special_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4']
name_columns = ['a', 'id_2', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'id_4', 'c']
a = []


for el in name_columns:
    if el in special_columns:
        a.insert(0, el)#insert in the beggining of the resulting list
    else:
        a.append(el)

print a
['id_4', 'to_date', 'from_date', 'id_2', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: True... I do not need to sort it. I could simply create a new one like you have done.

Comment: Note that the `insert` method isn't very efficient, especially when you insert near the start of the list, because all the subsequent items have to be moved each time you perform an insertion. True, that happens at C speed, but it's still better if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a dict that contains the order info of the special items. Creating a dict beforehand is much more efficient than calling the `.index` method on every item that you want to sort. The trick is to assign zero to the non-special items, and negative numbers to the special items, and then sort in reverse, so that the non-special items will always come at the end of the sorted list.

```
special_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4']
name_columns = ['a', 'id_2', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'id_4', 'c']

special_order = {u: i for i, u in enumerate(reversed(special_columns), 1)}
name_columns.sort(key=lambda s: special_order.get(s, 0), reverse=True)
print(name_columns)
```

**output**

```
['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_2', 'id_4', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

> In one line you try :

```
special_columns = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4']
name_columns = ['a', 'id_2', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'id_4', 'c']


new=[]
final=[[new.append(item),name_columns.remove(item)]  for item in special_columns if item in name_columns]

new.extend(name_columns)

print(new)
```

> Detailed solution:

```
ordered=[]
for item in special_columns:
    if item in name_columns:
        ordered.append(item)
        name_columns.remove(item)


ordered.extend(name_columns)
print(ordered)
```

output:

```
['from_date', 'to_date', 'id_2', 'id_4', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you. This is quite similar to the answer given by @v100ev (not identical though)

Comment: @mortysporty its not same approach, i am removing and then extending while he is inserting. :)